# how to append difference in a file to another file

Tags: diff

I am a forgetful person so I use every kind of backup utility. One of them is ClipIt, it stores up to 1000 items but I don't want to lose items that exceed the limit. I thought I can use `diff` tool and append new items to another file every day but I don't know how to do that. Would any smart person help me please?

Comment: Append? Like using `>>`: http://heatware.net/linux-unix/how-to-append-stringdata-to-a-file-in-linux/ ? Or maybe [`cat`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat)?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on the net, it's comm utility.

Show lines that only exist in file a:

```
 comm -23 a b
```

Show lines that only exist in file b:

```
 comm -13 a b
```

Show lines that only exist in one file or the other:

```
 comm -3 a b | sed 's/^\t//'
```

I use it like this:

EDIT:
I forgot to mention, ClipIt "history" file  in data format so it must be converted to text at first because comm can not compare binary data files.

```
 strings history >>file1

 comm -23  file1 file2 >>file2
```

Another workaround for ClipIt history limit; I grabbed the source code of it and increased the max values. It's working for the time being